# Problem with progress dialog not progressing Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i have a problem with my progress dialog. the progress dialog appears but i see no progress. i don't know what i'm doing wrong.Here is my code:

```
case R.id.fill_metal_pieces_table:
            MyApplication myApp = ((MyApplication)getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            boolean tablepopulated = myApp.getMetalPiecesTablePopulated();
            if(tablepopulated == false){
                myApp.setMetalPiecesTablePopulated(true);
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressDialog.setMax(652);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Chargement...");
                progressDialog.setTitle("Remplissage de la table");
                progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Looper.prepare();
                        handler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper()){
                            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                                super.handleMessage(msg);
                                progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(msg.what);
                            }
                        };
                        Looper.loop();
                        AssetManager am = getContext().getAssets();
                        InputStream is = null;
                        try {
                            is = am.open("catalogue.xls");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Workbook wb = null;
                        try {
                            wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (BiffException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(0);
                        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(getContext());
                        MetalPiece metalPiece;
                        for(int row = 1; row <= 652; row ++){
                            String typeMetalPiece = sheet.getCell(0, row).getContents();
                            String weightMetalPiece = sheet.getCell(1, row).getContents();
                            metalPiece = new MetalPiece();
                            metalPiece.setType(typeMetalPiece);
                            metalPiece.setWeight(Float.parseFloat(weightMetalPiece));
                            metalPiece.setFamily("Profile");
                            metalPiece.setUnit("Métre");
                            db.saveMetalPiece(metalPiece);
                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("tab","metalpiece");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
            else{
                Toast statusMetalPiecesTable = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "La table des piéces métalliques est déja remplie",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                statusMetalPiecesTable.show();
            }
            return true;
```

i'm writing code to fill a table with some data from an excel file. can you please me help with this issue . thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace `new Handler(Looper.myLooper())` with `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` or create it outside `Thread` - as `progressDialog` should/must be updated in main UI `Thread`, not some custom `Thread` with own loop

also: use `Log.i("some tag", "some value");` for logging steps and find out at which part code doesn't exceute properly (does `Handler` even gets these messages for redirecting to `progressDialog`? put inside `handleMessage` method `Log.i("some tag", "handleMessage msg.what:" + msg.what);`). Logs are show in Android Studio Logcat tab on the bottom of IDE

Comment: i tried both solution but none of them works